# Consumer connecting to zookeeper not broker for message consumption?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Per this document at [Kafka tutoria](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_tutorial.pdf)

Zookeper is started at port 2181
Broker/Kafka started at 9092

**Start Producer to Send Messages**

```
    bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Hello-Kafka // producer is producing directly to broker not zookeeper which is correct
```

**Start Consumer to Receive Messages**

```
    bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 —topic Hello-Kafka --from-beginning
```

Per mine understanding consumer consumes message directly from broker but in above consumer command  we did not mention broker but only zookeeper. Will
consumer connect to zookeeper(instead of broker) to consume message ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is as old Kafka consumer (0.8.2 and earlier) and a new Kafka consumer (0.9 and above). For a great description of how the new consumer works see the original announcement blog here

https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

The old consumer would connect to zookeeper but still would fetch all messages from Kafka.

The new consumer has no zookeeper dependency and does not connect to zookeeper at all.

The console-producer and console-consumer supports both the old an new apis depending on which options you give it. The example console-consumer you have provided is the old consumer because it specifies --zookeeper instead of --bootstrap-server

Comment: Iinstalled latest kafka i.e kafka-0.11.0.0-src from `https://kafka.apache.org/downloads`. As first step I am trying to make zookeeper server up. I am using zookeeper bundled with above kafka download. I navigated to `<Kafka_Dir>\bin\windows` and executed this command `zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties` but it says `The syntax of the command is incorrect.Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running gradlew jarAll` I am not sure what I am missing here ?

Comment: You downloaded the source code. You want to download the binary version so it will just run. Since you are on Windows which is not well supported I would recommend you use the docker images. Full QuickStart here http://docs.confluent.io/current/cp-docker-images/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks binary download worked.  I executed the following consumer command `kafka-console-consumer.bat  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning` It says `Missing required argument [zookeeper]`. Even kafka latest version consumer is expecting zookeeper ?

Comment: Works for me and should not be needed. Try explicitly setting --new-consumer which should be the default. It's possible you might have some older version of Kafka in your CLASSPATH. Running kafka-console-consumer.bat with no arguments should print all the options

Comment: can you please throw light at mine last comment under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621198/message-delivered-to-one-consumer-per-group ?

Answer (score 4):

What are you using with the --zookeeper parameter is the old consumer. The new Kafka consumer (you should use it) connects to a Kafka broker directly. For doing this, you can use the --bootstrap-server option instead of the --zookeeper specifying localhost:9092. The new consumer doesn't save offset on Zookeeper anymore but on a Kafka broker to a specific topic named __consumer_offsets.

Comment: So, the replacement for (OLD) command, bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 —topic Hello-Kafka --from-beginning (NEW) bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --broker-server localhost:9082 —topic Hello-Kafka --from-beginning (There is change to port number as well ! missed that at first). Do we still need to install zookeeper ?

Answer (score -1):

Consumer subscribe to topic and connect to zookeeper.The Kafka servers share information via a Zookeeper cluster. Kafka stores basic metadata in Zookeeper such as information about topics, brokers, consumer offsets (queue readers) and so on.For better understating for the role of zookeeper look for below link.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-role-of-ZooKeeper-in-Kafka

Comment: Consumer offsets are now stored in Kafka, not zookeeper. Only the old consumer 0.8 or earlier stores offsets in zookeeper